# How do I create a new routing table on the Ubiquity edgerouter4

Tags: networking, ubiquity

I am trying to configure a Ubiquity EdgeRouter-4 with a vlan on eth1 and DHCP WAN on eth0 I am including pics of the configuration I have so far. My main question is how do I create a new routing table and associate it with my vlan? I do not see any way to do it in the GUI and can't find any documentation on routing tables in the documentation other than to references to ones used but not how to set them up.

Also here is a link to the question on the Ubiquity website:
https://community.ui.com/questions/How-do-I-create-and-associate-routing-tables-on-the-EdgeRouter-4/4bfc8348-e1fc-4d63-8a28-2fd213c7bec7

[image: Dashboard]
[image: DNS]
[image: NAT]
[image: Routes]
[image: Routing table and routes in CLI]